# imap-login: Disconnected

Tags: linux, centos, email, imap

I have an email server with public dns entry that sends and receives fine.

I am trying to add it to outlook as imap account but it keeps failing. Server error shows

`Oct 30 15:29:04 mail.example.local dovecot[17250]: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<user@example.local>, method=PLAIN, rip=12.123.456.789, lip=123.4.56.7, session=<yjdfyjfkugih>`

`Oct 30 15:29:08 mail.example.local auth[17491]: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): check pass; user unknown`

```
cat /etc/pam.d/dovecot
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_nologin.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
session    include      password-auth
auth       required     pam_unix.so nullok
account    required     pam_unix.so
```

`cat auth-system.conf.ext
 PAM authentication. Preferred nowadays by most systems.
 PAM is typically used with either userdb passwd or userdb static.
 REMEMBER: You'll need /etc/pam.d/dovecot file created for PAM
 authentication to actually work. <doc/wiki/PasswordDatabase.PAM.txt>
passdb {
  driver = pam
  # [session=yes] [setcred=yes] [failure_show_msg=yes] [max_requests=<n>]
  # [cache_key=<key>] [<service name>]
  #args = dovecot
}`

Comment: Have you previosuly connected successfully using a different email client? Have you tried authenticating your imap user locally... using `doveadm` ... [Doveadm-auth reference page](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Auth)

Comment: `[root@server ]# doveadm auth test -x service=imap -x` 
`rip=192.168.10.8 testuser`
`Password:`
`passdb: testuser auth succeeded`
`extra fields:`
`user=testuser` 
This works fine but cant authenticate when using outlook or thunderbird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, after following this guide http://xmodulo.com/enable-user-authentication-postfix-smtp-server-sasl.html

It still didn't work, but turns out it was because my password had a '£' in which was causing the issue.